# cant place login button on right side in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Articles List</title>
    <?= link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Articles</a>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Login</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</nav>



</body>
</html>
```

I want to place the login button on right side of the navbar, but cant do it pull-right, float-right, navbar-right not working

Comment: please create a working example of your issue or provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Articles List</title>
    <?= link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Articles</a>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-2 my-sm-0" style="float: right" type="submit">Login</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</nav>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage people to explain why they have provided the code or approached the problem in the way they have.

Answer (score 0):

Your form isn't that wide. Please add *display: block* to *.form-inline* and pull-right to your button

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Articles List</title>
    <?= link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Articles</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="width: 100%">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-2 my-sm-0 pull-right" type="submit">Login</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a `class login` to the login button and in `CSS` added `position:relative;` and `float:right;`.

Try this:

```css
.login
{
   position:relative;
   float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Articles List</title>
    <?= link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Articles</a>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-2 my-sm-0 login" type="submit">Login</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</nav>



</body>
</html>
```